# How to view and modify incoming HTTP post data size limits

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I am using Iron-Router with my Meteor app to accept incoming HTTP requests. How do I know what the POST data size limits are? How do I set the limit for it?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about how to check the limits, but you can set limits with the following code:

```
Router.configureBodyParsers = function() {
    Router.onBeforeAction(Iron.Router.bodyParser.urlencoded({
        extended : true,
        limit : "8mb"
    }));
};
```

Comment: Sweet, thanks. I'll try it out to see if it works. Can you provide a reference for the code?