# Get data size of HTTP request and response

Tags: node.js, meteor, iron-router

I'm trying to manage my Meteor web app's API usage and have two questions.

1. How do I know how the size of the incoming POST request data? Note that I don't care about the contribution from headers; I just want to know the size of the data part.
2. How do I calculate a priori the amount of data that will be transferred if I respond to an HTTP call with JSON?

I am open to using Iron Router or Node's HTTP package. I previously asked about [setting some limits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30749930/how-to-view-and-modify-incoming-http-post-data-size-limits), but in this case I want to calculate and keep track of how much data is going in and out of my app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You could get the content header element `content-length`, but from what I understand, this field isn't guaranteed. 
   Could you check the size of the retrieved POST data after it has arrived?
   Node also specifies that

> Note: Node does not check whether Content-Length and the length of the body which has been transmitted are equal or not.
>   https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_class_http_clientrequest

2. You could get the length of the string as the bytes after the json is serialized. But I don't think this will be an accurate representation of bandwidth use, considering compression.  If you are interested in memory, you could use object-sizeof(https://www.npmjs.com/package/object-sizeof). This module takes assumptions based on the memory allocation of the objects, so its probably ill fitted for this purpose.